# Selenium RemoteWebDriver with ChromeOptions, constructor unavailable?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, remotewebdriver

I am having trouble creating a new RemoteWebDriver, and passing in ChromeOptions, using java 1.8 and the 3.141.59 jars.  See below. (I want to add other options as well, but at this point, I am just trying to get the constructor to work).

```
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

String hostUrl = "http://" + host + ":" + port + "/wd/hub";

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");

DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

//this is not an available constructor?
RemoteWebDriver   driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hostUrl),options);

//but this is?
RemoteWebDriver   driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hostUrl),caps);
```

Comment: Check your version of Selenium . In 3.141.59( ChromeOptions <-- MutableCapabilities <-- AbstractCapabilities <-- Capabilities ) RemoteWebDriver   driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hostUrl),options); Its available

Comment: Doh, was compiling with an earlier version of selenium , thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is present in the [selenium-remote-driver 3.141.59](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-remote-driver/3.141.59)

[image]

Most probably you have either different version of the `selenium-remote-driver` library in your project [classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) or another .jar has another version of the `selenium-remote-driver` in its [transitive dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies) therefore you're suffering from a [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell)

I would recommend using a dependency management solution like [Maven](https://experitest.com/blogs/testng_framework_maven/) or [Gradle](https://github.com/vicsz/testng-selenium-gradle-example) so you will not have to take care of dependent .jar libraries yourself, this will help you to avoid such situations in future.